# OAuth API call parameters not specific

Tags: php, api, oauth, freelancer.com-api

I've been working for the first time with OAuth lately, I've gotten the access token fine along with everything before it but I've stumbled with what I assumed would be the easiest part :(

The API call requires a parameter which isn't very specific, they just call it 'oauth'. I'm already putting my access token and secret into the signature, what should be in the 'oauth' parameter?

[Here's](http://developer.freelancer.com/GetInboxMessages) what I'm talking about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For oAuth 1.0 (Twitter) Here's what an oAuth HTTP header may look like:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="*****", oauth_nonce="fcde5bfc94d489c307f59aa384df9ef3", oauth_signature="tWE9gf3Dw0rBiKkN%2BcgO%2Fz%2FE%2FjA%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1335428402", oauth_token="*****", oauth_version="1.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, however I'm only really concerned with what I need to do after I have the access token, your example is for before this right?

Comment: I believe you need to pass in your access token for further queries as well. You definitely need to use it in your signature.